# How to show a specific div in a view from controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use two divs in a view. If I am logged in as a user I want to show the div named as 'user'. If logged in as an admin I want to load a view which has div named as 'admin'. I want to do this in CodeIgniter. 
My sample code is as follows,

```
if ($Admin == 0)
{
    $data['visible']=$this->login_model->show_menu();
}
else
{
    echo "I'm Admin";
    $this->load->view('home');  
}
```

Comment: You can give variable at your view. The doc :`$data['page_title'] = 'Your title'; $this->load->view('content', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

The doc : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Adding Dynamic Data to the View 
Let's try it with your controller file. Open it add this code:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
        $data['heading'] = "My Real Heading";

        $this->load->view('blogview', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Now open your view file and change the text to variables that correspond to the array keys in your data:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So, in your case, you can do something like that :

```
if ($Admin == 0)
{
    $data['visible']=$this->login_model->show_menu();
}
else
{
    $data['visible']='admin';
    echo "I'm Admin";
    $this->load->view('home', $data);  
}
```

And in your view :

```
if($visible == 'admin') {
    echo '<div>Your admin display</div>';
}
else {
    echo '<div>',$visible,'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Ellislab does not look into CodeIgniter now. CodeIgniter's manual is moved to: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?highlight=views

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 variables

`$showAdmin` and `$showUser`

In controller

```
function showView() {
 $showAdmin = FALSE;
 $showUser = FALSE;
 if ($isAdminLoggedInYourCode) {
  $showAdmin = TRUE;
 }
 else if ($isUserLoggedInYourCode) {
  $showUser = TRUE;
 }
 $data['showAdmin'] = $showAdmin;
 $data['showUser'] = $showUser;
 $this->load->view('home', $data); 
}
```

And in view,

```
if ($showAdmin) {
 // Show Admin div
}
else if ($showUser) {
 // Show User div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
if ($Admin == 0)
{
    $data['visible']=$this->login_model->show_menu();
}
else
{
    echo "I'm Admin";
    $this->load->view('home');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two different views for user and admin

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function index()
    {
        $data = getSomeStuff(); 
        $admin = checkAdmin();

        if($admin == 0) {
            $this->load->view('user', $data);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('admin', $data);
        }
    }
}
```